# Google Apps Script Chart Use row 1 as headers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

I have the following chart:

```
var ss = ... // get sheet
var chart = ss.newChart().asLineChart();
chart.setTitle("My Title");
chart.addRange(dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 4));
chart.setColors(["#3c78d8", "#a61c00", "#38761d"]);
chart.setXAxisTitle("X Title");
chart.setYAxisTitle("Y Title");
chart.setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);
chart.setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH);
ss.insertChart(chart.build());
```

This code will use the show the first row as part of the data, instead of using it to label the legend.  As a side note, if I use asColumnChart instead of line chart, it does the right thing.

How can I tell a chart to use the first row as headers using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off - your code is OK. I took a copy and made minor changes to it just to use a single sheet for illustration:

[image: Chart Screenshot - all good]

The problem is likely with your data, specifically the first row. Here's that same example, with some of the "Headers" changed from text into numbers. I believe it is behaving in the bad way you're describing.

[image: Chart Screenshot - problems]

One more time, but with the numbers in the header forced to be text. (In the spreadsheet, I input them as `'4` and `'5` - the leading single quote tells Spreadsheet to treat as text.)

[image: Chart Screenshot - all good again]

Just take a look at the data types in your first row, and make sure that they are Text.

Comment: As of today, this approach is no longer working for me.