# Google Script Charts Excludes Header by Default

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

Using the following script:

```
function chartCreation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var chart = sheet.newChart().asColumnChart()
    .setTitle('Test Chart')
    .addRange(sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 4))
    .setPosition(1,1,0,0)
  sheet.insertChart(chart.build()); 
}
```

Produces a chart like this one, in which the legend is empty (i.e. the data series are unlabeled).
[image: Chart Example]

I've read that it could be due to the format of my header row, which should be text (which mine is, but it doesn't seem to be used). If I try to build it within Google Sheets, though the chart builder dialog, it works just fine and includes the data series labels.

How do I set the "use row 1 as headers" option with Google Apps Script?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611197/google-apps-script-chart-use-row-1-as-headers) is similar, but has no answer pertaining to non-text format.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** This post is based on this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176895/google-script-use-row-x-as-headers) and works even for column charts. Even though column charts [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) dont document it. 
Legend values can be set using a `labelInLegend` in the `series` configuration options as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#configuration-options).(Navigate to the option series)

Your code will look something like this:

```
function chartCreation() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,4).getValues()
var chart = sheet.newChart().asColumnChart()
.setTitle('Test Chart')
.addRange(sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 4))
.setPosition(1,1,0,0)
.setOption('series', 
     {0:{labelInLegend:headerRow[0][1]},
      1:{labelInLegend:headerRow[0][2]},
      2:{labelInLegend:headerRow[0][3]}})
 sheet.insertChart(chart.build()); 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. Looks like it has to do with the headerRow. My headers are A1:D1 so it looks fine to me, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Had a syntax wrong on this line 'var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,4).getValues'. It's fixed now, try the updated code. Thanks