# Google Script - Use row x as headers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a system that makes line graphs and scatterplots in google sheets. As of March 7th, 2018 the graphs started to include the 1 row of my data as part of the graph rather than headers of the column.

If i make the graph manually then it will make my row one the headers of the graph. Also if i edit the current graph and tick the Use row x as headers then my header will be back to how they use to be.

My question is if there is a way i can program this in google script or a work around i can use.

Some thing I tried was following this guide:
[Google Apps Script Chart Use row 1 as headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611197/google-apps-script-chart-use-row-1-as-headers)

but as someone else commented it no longer works, and in my test it didnt.

Thank you!

Edit: This is how i build the chart:

```
var currChart = currSheet.newChart();
currChart.setPosition (row, col, 5,5)
var builtChart = currChart.asScatterChart()
                        .addRange(currRange)
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setYAxisTitle(axisLabel)
                        .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain','true')
                        .setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min', min)
                        .setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', max)
                        .setOption('chartArea.left', 80)
                        .setOption('chartArea.top', 60)
                        .setOption('chartArea.width', 360)
                        .setOption('chartArea.height', 240)
                        .setOption('chartArea.backgroundColor',
                                  { stroke: "#828282", strokeWidth: 2, fill: "#fcfcfc" })
                        .setOption('series', 
                                  {0:{color: '#54B4C6', pointSize: 3, pointShape: 'circle'},
                                   1:{color: '#2F53D9', pointSize: 10, pointShape: 'diamond'},
                                   2:{color: '#F1BE00', pointSize: 4, pointShape: 'circle'},
                                   3:{color: '#D90D0C', pointSize: 11, pointShape: 'diamond'}})
                        .build();

currSheet.insertChart(builtChart);
```

Comment: Nearly an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176237/google-script-charts-excludes-header-by-default)

Comment: @Brian Your answer pertains to column charts and transposing them works. However, scatter plots cannot be transposed.

Comment: Both questions are about setting the legend values from a specific row, which isn't doable right now with in the `EmbeddedChartBuilder` class, regardless of type. The solution for the column chart is a hacky workaround (and might not even solve the problem).

Comment: Im not sure i can do that cause im processing about 5,000 points of data per sheet page. I think i would hit the time limit

Comment: @Brian I am not sure of legends in column charts. However, legends can be defined in the scatter plot as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: @JackBrown Thanks for the clarification. It isn't in the column chart options. It's always a mystery why options vary between classes, especially with such a subtle difference like this.

Comment: @Brian I tried the below code on a column chart and it seems to set the legend! But the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) doesn't mention it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set legend values using a `labelInLegend` in the `series` configuration options as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#configuration-options).(Navigate to the option series)

So in your above code lets assume you have extracted your first row in a array like so:

```
 var values = currRange.getValues()
 var headerRow = []
 for (var i =0; i<values[0].length ; i++)
   headerRow[i] = values[0][i]
```

You can set the values of your series using setOptions like so:

```
.setOption('series', 
            {0:{color: '#54B4C6', pointSize: 3, pointShape: 'circle',labelInLegend:headerRow[1]},
             1:{color: '#2F53D9', pointSize: 10, pointShape: 'diamond',labelInLegend:headerRow[2]},
             2:{color: '#F1BE00', pointSize: 4, pointShape: 'circle',labelInLegend:headerRow[3]},
             3:{color: '#D90D0C', pointSize: 11, pointShape: 'diamond',labelInLegend:headerRow[4]}})
```

In short, just include the following `key:value` pair `lableInLegend:'Header Value'`in your series object. 
**Note:** Skip the first value of the header, as that pertains to the vertical axis.
Your final code will like so:

```
var values = currRange.getValues()
 var headerRow = []
 for (var i =0; i<values[0].length ; i++)
   headerRow[i] = values[0][i]
 var currChart = currSheet.newChart();
  currChart.setPosition (row, col, 5,5)
 var builtChart = currChart.asScatterChart()
                    .addRange(currRange)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setYAxisTitle(axisLabel)
                    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain','true')
                    .setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min', min)
                    .setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', max)
                    .setOption('chartArea.left', 80)
                    .setOption('chartArea.top', 60)
                    .setOption('chartArea.width', 360)
                    .setOption('chartArea.height', 240)
                    .setOption('chartArea.backgroundColor',
                              { stroke: "#828282", strokeWidth: 2, fill: "#fcfcfc" })
                        .setOption('series', 
                                   {0:{color: '#54B4C6', pointSize: 3, pointShape: 'circle',labelInLegend:headerRow[1]},
                                   1:{color: '#2F53D9', pointSize: 10, pointShape: 'diamond',labelInLegend:headerRow[2]},
                                   2:{color: '#F1BE00', pointSize: 4, pointShape: 'circle',labelInLegend:headerRow[3]},
                                   3:{color: '#D90D0C', pointSize: 11, pointShape: 'diamond',labelInLegend:headerRow[4]}})
                        .build();
currSheet.insertChart(builtChart);
```

Comment: Okay ill try this today and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: How do i get values when they are coming from a range of formula.